# Thrift: Serialize + Deserialize changes object

Tags: java, thrift, thrift-protocol

I have a thrift struct something like this:

```
struct GeneralContainer {
    1: required string identifier;
    2: required binary data;
}
```

The idea is to be able to pass different types of thrift objects on a single "pipe", and still be able to deserialize at the other side correctly.

But serializing a `GeneralContainer` object, and then deserializing it changes the contents of the `data` field. I am using the `TBinaryProtocol`:

```
TSerializer serializer = new TSerializer(new TBinaryProtocol.Factory());
TDeserializer deserializer = new TDeserializer(new TBinaryProtocol.Factory());

GeneralContainer container = new GeneralContainer();
container.setIdentifier("my-thrift-type");
container.setData(ByteBuffer.wrap(serializer.serialize(myThriftTypeObject)));

byte[] serializedContainer = serializer.serialize(container);
GeneralContainer testContainer = new GeneralContainer();
deserializer.deserialize(testContainer, serializedContainer);
Assert.assertEquals(container, testContainer);  // fails
```

My guess is that some sort of markers are getting messed up when we serialize an object containing binary field using `TBinaryProtocol`. Is that correct? If yes, what are my options for the protocol? My goal is to minimize the size of resulting serialized byte array.

Thanks,
Aman

Comment: update: runs using `TCompactProtocol`

Answer (score 0):

Tracked it to a bug in thrift 0.4 serialization. Works fine in thrift 0.8.